# In Remix run app, making 3rd party API call on server side to get the data and populate form drop downs

Tags: remix.run

In my Remix run app, I have a page with few components - radio button, input field, drop downs. After filling all the fields , I need to submit which should make a 3rd party API call for saving the data.

Now first drop down is suppose to be populated with 3rd party API GET call which should be triggered on Radio button selection and based on selected value. Similarly, second drop down suppose to be populated with 3rd party API GET call which should be triggered on first drop down selection and based on selected value.

My question is. --

1. What is the ideal way to make 3rd party API call? Should it be on client side or it should be server side.
2. If I need to do on server side, I am not sure what should be ideal approach to make these API calls to get the data to populate form components based on selections.

I understand that on final submission I can use `action` to submit the form and make 3rd party API call for saving the data.

Comment: You should do it server side, using `useFetcher` to make a request to an `action` when a radio button is selected. Same for the dropdowns, you just need to distinguish between the requests with a field you set

Comment: Do you have the code for what you tried?

Comment: Thanks @Nullndr for the pointers. I have posted my solution below. It works but do you think its ideal way or there is any better way of doing it.

Comment: @Hashanhemachandra I have posted my approach in the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried below solution which is working -

In my React component I am using useFetcher and doing fetcher.load() inside a function which is called on any dropdown value selection. In fetcher.load() I am passing route path of the loader where I have defined actual 3rd party API call to get the data. In useEffect of the component I am checking if data is fetched. if yes then setting in local useState.

Sample code -

routes/myComponent.tsx

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const myAppFetcher = useFetcher();     
  const [appEnvs, setAppEnvs] = useState("someValue");
  const [myAppData, setMyAppData] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (myAppFetcher.state === 'idle' && myAppFetcher.data != null) {
      setMyAppData(myAppFetcher.data);
    }
  }, [myAppFetcher]);

  // loadMyApp will be called on any drop down value select and pass 
  // the selected value appEnv in the loader
  const loadMyApp = async (appEnv: string) => {
    myAppFetcher.load(`/data/myAppLoader?appEnv=${appEnv}`);
  };
}
```

/routes/data/myAppLoader.ts

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }: ActionArgs) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const appEnv = url.searchParams.get('appEnv');
  const data = await myAppDataFromApi(appEnv);
  return json(data);
};
```

Comment: You don't need that `useEffect`, I think it is ok then